# How to combine 2 scripts into one

Tags: bash, file, scripting

I'm searching for a way to combine these 2 scripts into one:

[Script 1](https://ghostbin.com/paste/wq33g)
[Script 2](https://ghostbin.com/paste/u3253)

I take the first script that places the files in a directory.
I was able to modify it to write in a different folder.
But I must use just one. How can I do this?

Comment: don't make 2 scripts. Just store `it.lproj/` in a variable at the start of your scipt, i.e. add `MYPATH='it.lproj/'` right after `#!/bin/bash`. Then, through your script, replace the occurences of `it.lproj/` with `$MYPATH`. That way, when you want to switch from 1 version of your script to another, just do `MYPATH='it.lproj/'` or `MYPATH=''`

Comment: Thanks, but look the comments down. I need just one script that will run both because it will be in a .deb so I can't/don't want chiose which run. Thanks again!

Comment: then just do `./script1;./script2` ?

Comment: Huh? Sorry but As I said I'm totally noob in scripting :( Can you make me an example (or do it with my 2 scripts)

Answer (score 0):

As noted it's enough to see where the files are different and to substitute in those lines the parts that play a similar role. In this case you can do it with a single variable. Better if protected with `{}`.
In this case you can run the script and pass to it the *subpath* you want:

`./myscript.sh ../Napster.app/it.lproj`
or
`./myscript.sh ../Napster.app`

if you run it without parameter it will use as default `../Napster.app/it.lproj`

```
#!/bin/sh
MyPath=${1:-../Napster.app/it.lproj"}

if [ -f "/var/mobile/temp.temp" ];then
rm "/var/mobile/temp.temp"
fi

ls -d /var/mobile/Applications/*/*.app | sort -f -t \/ -k 6 | while read OneApp
do
        AppName=$(echo $OneApp | cut -f 6 -d '/')
        cd "$OneApp";
devicebundleid=$(plutil -key CFBundleIdentifier Info.plist)
if [ "$devicebundleid" = "com.rhapsody.iphone.Napster3" ]; then
        pwd >/var/mobile/temp.temp
fi
done
if [ ! -f "/var/mobile/temp.temp" ];then
        echo "Napster not found. if your sure its install please report to the repo manager"
else
        dir=$(cat "/var/mobile/temp.temp")
        backup="$dir/../backup.tar.gz"
        gamefiles=/files.tmp
        hackedfiles=/hackedfiles.tmp
        matchingfiles=/matchingfiles.tmp
        itunesmeta=$dir/../iTunesMetadata.plist
        info=$dir/Info.plist
        binname=$(plutil -key CFBundleExecutable $dir/Info.plist)


        if [ -f $dir/../iTunesMetadata.plist ];then
                if grep -q "bundleShortVersionString" "$itunesmeta"
                then myappver=$(plutil -key bundleShortVersionString $itunesmeta)
                else myappver=$(plutil -key bundleVersion $itunesmeta)
                fi
        else
                plutil -xml $info  2>&1>/dev/null
                if grep -q "CFBundleShortVersionString" "$info"
                then myappver=$(plutil -key CFBundleShortVersionString $info)
                else myappver=$(plutil -key CFBundleVersion $info)
                fi
        fi

        echo "###########"
        echo "# Description #"
        echo "###########"
        echo "XX SUPERGIU XX"
        sleep 1
        echo

        echo "######"
        echo "# Log #"
        echo "######"

        echo -n " -Checking Files..."
        if [ ! -d "/hack" ]; then
                echo
                echo " *** Error ***"
                echo
                echo "***********************************************"
                echo "   *No files found in /hack***"
                echo "   *Please report this to the repo manager"
                echo
                echo "***********************************************"
                echo
                exit 0
        else
                sleep 1
                echo " Success"
        fi

        echo -n " -Finding Napster..."
        sleep 1
        echo " Success"

        echo -n " -Locating Matching Files..."
        sleep .1
        echo " Success"

        echo -n " -Making Backup..."    
        ls $dir/${MyPath}/ >$gamefiles
        ls "/hack" >$hackedfiles
        grep -i -E -f $gamefiles $hackedfiles >$matchingfiles

        for line in `cat $matchingfiles`
        do tar -pczf "$dir/../backup.tar.gz" "$dir/${MyPath}/$line"&>/dev/null
        done
        if [ -f "$dir/../backup.tar.gz" ]; then
                sleep 1
                echo " Success"
        else
                sleep 1
                echo " *** Error ***"
                echo
                echo "***********************************************"
                echo "  *Backup not needed, not replacing anything"
                echo
                echo "***********************************************"
        fi

        echo -n " -Checking App Version..."
        if [ ! "200" == "$myappver" ]; then
                sleep 1
                echo " *** Error ***"
                echo
                echo "***********************************************"
                echo "*** Your app is version $myappver ***"
                echo "*** This file is for 200 ***"
                echo "*** It may not work, please get version 200 ***"
                echo
                echo "***********************************************"
        else 
                sleep 1
                echo " Success"
        fi

        echo -n " -Patching Files..."
        sleep 1
        echo " Success"
        mv -f /hack/* "$dir/${MyPath}/"

        echo -n " -Setting Ownership and Permissions..."
        sleep 1
        echo " Success"
        chmod -R 755 "$dir/${MyPath}/"
        chown -R mobile.mobile "$dir/${MyPath}/"
        if [ $sign = "1" ];then
        ldone "$dir/$binname" -s
        fi

        echo -n " -Cleaning Up..."

        sleep 1
        echo " Success"
        rm -f $gamefiles $hackedfiles $matchingfiles $dirfile
        rmdir /hack

        echo " -Successfully Done :)"
        sleep .5
        echo

        echo "###########"
        echo "# Credits #"
        echo "###########"

        echo " -By SUPERGIU"
        echo
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, but this script will run automatically in a deb (as a postinst) so I can't decide which script run. I need a script that will run both script automatically in one

Comment: If I understand you well...What about to do a script that run the first and after the second?

Comment: Yeah, this would be nice, but I don't know how to do it. (These scripts are generated with a Program, I didn't write them). Sorry, I'm not really good in scripting

Comment: As just written somewhere do another script in the same directory of the other 2 (it's not needed but simpler), call it e.g. `Run2.sh` and write inside `/bin/bash MyScript1.sh` and in the second line `/bin/bash MyScript2.sh`. After save and write from that directory `/bin/bash Run2.sh`.